# mysql charset causes a error in my login form

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

The problem is that everytime (also when I type in the right username and password combination) the error message "Failed 2" appears.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["login-submit"])) {
    if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
      $username = $_POST["username"];
      $password = $_POST["password"];
      $username = mysql_set_charset($username);
      $password = mysql_set_charset($password);
      $username = stripcslashes($username);
      $password = stripcslashes($password);
      $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
      $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
      $result = mysql_query("select * from user where username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      if($row["username"] == $username && $row["password"] == $password) {
        //header("Location: index.php");
        echo "<p>Login</p>";
      } else {
        echo "<p>Failed 2</p>";
      }
    } else {
      echo "<p>Failed 1</p>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to echo `$username` and `$password` before you run `mysql_query`? Your problem lies on the call `mysql_set_charset`. Take a look at its [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php). It only returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. It is used to set the charset for the connection.

Comment: the greatest mistake is not hashing your password! *everytime you store an unhashed password, root moves a kitten to /dev/null* - use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. also: you are using the outdated mysql-functions they are deprecated and in PHP7 **removed**, use mysqli or PDO instead. also: use parameterized statements - stipping slashes does **not** completely protect you from SQL injections

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: Lament: another new programmer writes their own crummy password verification scheme and so does their part to make the world safe for cybercriminals. Please read this.  http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php Please take it to heart.

Comment: Basically, your query failed and you need to find out why; check for errors via php and the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your helpful answers. I changed to mysqli. Now the code works. Here it is:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["login-submit"])) {
    if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
      $username = $_POST["username"];
      $password = $_POST["password"];
      $username = stripcslashes($username);
      $password = stripcslashes($password);
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
      $login = "select * from user where username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $login);
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      if ($count == 1) {
        //header("Location: index.php");
        echo "<p>Login</p>";
      } else {
        echo "<p>Failed 2</p>";
      }
    } else {
      echo "<p>Failed 1</p>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Possible problem could be:

- You are comparing plain password (from $_POST) with password that
  might be encrypted in the database. If this is the case make sure you
  encrypt your request password before you compare with saved password
- It could be the case that you have saved your username or password with trailing spaces. If this is the case make sure you trim your data before doing comparison
- Try to var_dump or print  $row (also $_POST) and see what you are getting for more information

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (PHP Data Objects) to run parameterized SQL queries.
It protects you against SQL injection and it speeds up your queries.

Then you can write something like this:
`$db = db($server, $user, $pass, $db); $sql = "select * from user where username =:username and password=:password"; $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); $stmt->bindParam("user", $yourPostUsername); $stmt->bindParam("pass", $yourPostPassword); $stmt->execute(); $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); if ($result) { echo "<p>Login</p>"; } else { echo "<p>Failed 2</p>"; }`